# Discrete "Zoom" Used in 2001: A Space Odyssey

Tags: cinematography, terminology

There is a "zoom" where a series of short clips, each one getting closer to the subject, are shown in quick succession. I've seen it in a number of movies and in possibly more than one Kubrick film.

[Here it is in 2001: A Space Odyssey.](https://youtu.be/-3m-Zu3qgM4?t=81)

Does this technique have a name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Axial Cut / Concentration Cut**

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_cut):

> An axial cut is a type of [jump cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_cut), where the camera suddenly moves closer to or further away from its subject, along an invisible line drawn straight between the camera and the subject. [...] [A]n axial cut is a way of maintaining the illusion of continuity.
>
> The intervening footage (as the camera moves or zooms) is then removed while editing the film.

David Bordwell's article [Seed-beds of style](http://www.davidbordwell.net/blog/2009/11/27/seed-beds-of-style/) has many picture showing the effect, e. g. the four pictures of the beaurocrat under siege in Dovzhenko’s Arsenal (1929). He notes

> The Soviets called such cuts “concentration cuts,” a good term for the way they make a figure seem to pop out at us. From being a simple enlargement (in tableau cinema) or one among many methods of penetrating the scene’s space (in Hollywood continuity), the axial cut has been given a new force, thanks to adding more shots and making them quite brief.

Regarding the scene from Odyssey 2001, it's notable how it stays on the axis. Here's a [video](https://vimeo.com/232821832) showing how Kurosawa and Hitchcock used that type of cut, sometimes more cloesely resembling what Kubrick did:

Regarding Kubrick, I found this [mention](https://www.cinescribe.fr/?p=1554) (in French) by Nausica-Zaballos-Dey:

> concentration cut (utilisé par Stanley Kubrick pour filmer l’oeil rouge et impassible de Hal 9000 dans 2001, l’odyssée de l’espace)

Comment: The cut is used almost the same way as it is in 2001 in the  Russian film Arsenal (1929):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2F7NfnrZ50I&feature=youtu.be&t=3622